# Traverse dataset to check for conditions

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, entity-framework

I apologize for the title, as I couldn't think of a concise way to phrase my issue. If anyone has a better description, please edit it.

Cycle (Database table)

```
int PartNo (PK)
int StepNo
string Group
Datetime Start
Datetime Finish
string Status
```

Example

```
PartNo  |  StepNo  |  Group  |  Start  |  Finish  |  Status
  0     |    0     | Group1  | 1-1-01  |  1-2-01  |    A
  0     |    1     | Group2  | 1-2-01  |  1-3-01  |    A
  0     |    2     | Group3  | 1-3-01  |  1-4-01  |    A
  0     |    3     | Group1  | 1-4-01  |  1-5-01  |    R
  0     |    4     | Group1  | 1-5-01  |  1-6-01  |    
  0     |    5     | Group1  | 1-6-01  |  1-7-01  |       
  0     |    6     | Group1  | 1-7-01  |          |    
  0     |    7     | Group2  |         |          |    
...more PartNo...
```

Let me start by giving a short description of what I need in "business" words. This table tracks an item as it is approved by several groups. As you can see in the example table, group1, group2, and group 3 approved the item, and it goes back to group1. The empty status fields represent reassignments within that group, and you can see that it has been reassigned a few times after being rejected in step 3. You can also tell the current step is 6 because it has a `start` time, but no `finish` time. There can be several rejects per PartNo.

Now here's a description of my tricky query. I need to check if there has been a recent rejection. This is defined by a rejection happening in the same group as the current group. The groups involved between the current step and rejection step must also be the same, `Group1` in this case, in order to be classified as a recent rejection. For this example, the current step is 6 and my query must return step 3, the location of the reject. To clarify, if step 4 or 5 were changed to any other group, the query would return nothing. I hope that makes sense.

I can craft a query to return the last rejected row, but I'm not really sure how to iterate through the rows between the current step and the rejected step to check groups.

Get current step

```
Cycle.Where(c => c.Start.HasValue() && !c.Finish.HasValue())
    .GroupBy(c => c.PartNo)
    .Select(g => new
    {
        PartNo = g.Key,
        StepNo = g.Min(s => s.StepNo)
    }
```

Get latest reject

```
Cycle.Where(c => c.Status == "R")
    .GroupBy(c => c.PartNo)
    .Select(g => new
    {
        PartNo = g.Key,
        StepNo = g.Max(s => s.StepNo)
    }
```

Any input on how to check the rows between the latest reject and current step will be much appreciated.

EDIT:

I'm thinking it might be possible to combine the two queries above into one table containing the `PartNo`, `CurrentStep`, and `RejectedStep`. From here, I could rejoin with cycle, which would give me all rows from the current step to the rejected step.

```
var combined = currentStep
            .Join(rejectedStep,
                    c => c.PartNo,
                    r => r.PartNo,
                    (c,r) => new { PartNo = c.PartNo, Current = c.StepNo, Reject = r.Stepno});
```

Insert some join query to get `StepNo <= Current && StepNo >= Reject`

I *COULD* use a `foreach` loop to check if the groups in each of these are the same, but I would much rather use LINQ so that the processing happens database side. How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I still may not be understanding your requirements. You said in your business description, you only wanted to return rows where the `Group` is the same as well as `PartNo`, but none of your code samples seem to take this into account. This query is not pretty, but it works:

```
var results = 
    from c in Cycles
    group c by new { c.PartNo, c.Group } into g
    let c = g.Where(s => s.Start.HasValue && !s.Finish.HasValue)
             .Select(s => s.StepNo)
    let r = g.Where(s => s.Status == "R")
             .Select(s => s.StepNo)
    where r.Any() && c.Any()
    select new 
    { 
        g.Key, 
        Steps = g.Where(s => s.StepNo <= c.Max() && s.StepNo >= r.Min()) 
    };
```

When run against your sample set, it returns:
[image: result set]

---

**Update**

Here's another stab at it. This query will exclude cases where the `group` column is  changed at any point between the rejected step (`r`) and the current step (`c`):

```
var results = 
    (from c in Cycles
    group c by c.PartNo into g
    let c = g.Where(s => s.Start.HasValue && !s.Finish.HasValue)
             .Select(s => s.StepNo)
    let r = g.Where(s => s.Status == "R")
             .Select(s => s.StepNo)
    where r.Any() && c.Any()
    let steps = g.Where(s => s.StepNo <= c.Max() && s.StepNo >= r.Min()) 
    where steps.Select(x => x.Group).Distinct().Count() == 1
    select new 
    { 
        g.Key, 
        Steps = steps
    }
```

Comment: I think this query is really close to what I require. Let me attempt to clarify. I wish to know if an item has been recently rejected. There exists some cases where a reject step is followed by reassignments within the group. I will know if an item is still "recently rejected" if all groups between the current step and the rejected step contain the same group. If the group changes at some point, that means the item has been accepted and proceeds to the next step. If all groups are the same between the rejected step and current step, I wish to return the rejected step. Hope that helps

Comment: Also, I think your use of grouping by `c.Group` may not work properly if there existed a reject, say, in step 1. Your query would return two sets of data for one PartNo, which is undesired.

Comment: Hah, a very intuitive solution you have come up with! `Select(x => x.Group).Distinct().Count() == 1`. Just what I needed!

Comment: @Jeff like I said, not pretty. plus I haven't tried to see what SQL it produces, so you may still want to do some tweaking, but I think it gets you on the right track.

Comment: Of course, I will be working on converting this to extension method syntax (my preference) and analyzing the generated sql. thanks!